# Translating loop syntax from Stata to R

Tags: r, stata

I need to write a for loop to calculate the product of year variables (e.g. var1874) * price variables (e.g. num1874), creating a new variable for each year and its corresponding price value (e.g. newvar1874).

Here's my data in R

```
A tibble: 4 x 7
    cty var1874 var1875 var1876 num1874 num1875 num1876
  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
1     1    0.78    0.83    0.99    2.64    2.8     3.1 
2     2    0.69    0.69    0.89    2.3     2.3     2.58
3     3    0.42    0.48    0.59    2.28    2.44    2.64
4     4    0.82    0.94    1.09    2.28    2.36    3
```

I've been able to do this using the 'foreach' loop in Stata:

```
local vn 1874 1875 1876

foreach v of local vn {
     gen newvar'v' = var'v'*num'v'
```

Does anyone know how I would do this same type of command using the for loop in R? I know there may be simpler ways to do this without the for loop, but I need to know how to do this using the for loop.

Comment: Not the question, but this data layout would not be good within Stata. A separate column (variable) for each year just commits users to unnecessary looping.

Comment: Regardless of using Stata or R, it would be easier to reshape the data to longer form, `newvar = var*num` without looping.

Answer (score 2):

Using a `for` loop you could do:

```r
vn <- 1874:1876

for (v in vn) d[[paste0("newvar", v)]] <- d[[paste0("var", v)]] * d[[paste0("num", v)]]

d
#>   cty var1874 var1875 var1876 num1874 num1875 num1876 newvar1874 newvar1875
#> 1   1    0.78    0.83    0.99    2.64    2.80    3.10     2.0592     2.3240
#> 2   2    0.69    0.69    0.89    2.30    2.30    2.58     1.5870     1.5870
#> 3   3    0.42    0.48    0.59    2.28    2.44    2.64     0.9576     1.1712
#> 4   4    0.82    0.94    1.09    2.28    2.36    3.00     1.8696     2.2184
#>   newvar1876
#> 1     3.0690
#> 2     2.2962
#> 3     1.5576
#> 4     3.2700
```

Or using `lapply` you could do:

```r
d[, paste0("newvar", vn)] <- lapply(vn, function(v) d[[paste0("var", v)]] * d[[paste0("num", v)]])
```

**DATA**

```
d <- structure(list(
  cty = 1:4, var1874 = c(0.78, 0.69, 0.42, 0.82),
  var1875 = c(0.83, 0.69, 0.48, 0.94), var1876 = c(
    0.99, 0.89,
    0.59, 1.09
  ), num1874 = c(2.64, 2.3, 2.28, 2.28), num1875 = c(
    2.8,
    2.3, 2.44, 2.36
  ), num1876 = c(3.1, 2.58, 2.64, 3)
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  "1",
  "2", "3", "4"
))
```

Comment: Ok thanks, how would I do that without specifying an object value 'd'? The loop seems unnecessary if I have to spell out everything in an object value.

Comment: First. As far as I get it from your question your variables are already stored inside a dataframe or tibble. That's the object which I named `d`. In general, in R the recommended or R-ish way would be to add new variables to the dataframe instead of creating separate variables in the global environment. As far as I remember that's one of the major differences compared to Stata or SPSS where there is no such thing as a data.frame, i.e. there is only one dataset and therefore all newly created variables will be automatically be added to this dataset.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm attempting to do: add new variables (the products) to the existing dataframe. How would I do that with a for loop without object 'd'?

Comment: Simply replace `d` in my code with the name you use for your dataframe.

Comment: Frames are supported in Stata.

Comment: @NickCox. Thx. Used Stata the last time 7 years ago and forgot almost everything.

Comment: Stata did not have frames 7 years ago.